# Sweet - Question

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, probability-theory

There are n sweets in a bag. Six of the sweets are orange. The rest of the sweets are yellow.

Hannah takes a sweet from the bag. She eats the sweet. Hannah then takes at random another sweet from the bag. She eats the sweet.

The probability that Hannah eats two orange sweets is $\frac1 3$. Show that $n^2-n-90=0$

Comment: Besides "sharing new ideas", what exactly is your question???

Answer (score 2):

Picking two sweets are independent events, so the probability is equal to the product of the probability of the two events separately, then you have:

$$1/3=\frac{6}{n} \cdot \frac{5}{n-1}$$

Which is equal to:

$$n^2-n = 90$$